# Grounding analogue signals through ads1115

Tags: sensors, arduino-nano, adafruit

Quick question - I have some [pretty expensive gas flow sensors](https://www.coleparmer.com/i/cole-parmer-low-cost-gas-mass-flowmeter-0-to-20-sccm-acetal/3270720?searchterm=32707-20) outputting a 0-5V signal, which need at least 2.5 KOhms minimum load. Can I connect them to the Adafruit ADS1115 breakout ([ADS1115 chip](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1115.pdf), [Adafruit breakout board circuit](https://learn.adafruit.com/assets/36145), [adafruit ferrite bead input impedance (or I think it is, pls correct me if I'm wrong)](https://www.mouser.co.uk/ProductDetail/TDK/MMZ2012Y152B?qs=G1TAZZK1RgIiLCxJKpiMEg==))? If I put a 2KOhm resistor (for example) from the ADS1115 GND to the arduino ground, will that solve this issue, if it exists?

Many thanks for your help

EDIT: The flowmeter manual is [here](https://archive-resources.coleparmer.com/Manual_pdfs/32707-xx.pdf). It states the impedance of the 0-5V receiver should be greater than 2.5KOhms.

Comment: It is unclear if the 2500Ω "minimum load" is the minimum resistance value of a load it can have before the voltage starts to droop, or if it's the maximum allowed resistance to create the minimum required current flow.  The "load strength" is generally taken to be the inverse of the resistance (a "stronger" load has a lower resistance). A proper datasheet is needed.

Comment: the product webpage that you provided contains a link to customer service for asking questions ... i suggest that you contact them

Comment: OK, will do that and get back to you, cheers

Comment: @Majenko and jsotola, Hi I got it - it states the receiver impedance should be greater than 2.5KOhms.

Comment: @OliverWalters Ok, so since an ADC is typically hundreds of kΩ or even MΩ, that's not a problem.